# Deleting queued jobs in Laravel 5

Tags: laravel-5, queue

I'm using database as queue driver in my system.
How can I delete a queued job that is stored in my jobs table?

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Implement the `Illuminate\Queue\InteractsWithQueue` trait which gives you access to the `delete()` method.

More information in the [API](http://laravel.com/api/5.1/Illuminate/Queue/InteractsWithQueue.html) and in the [docs](http://laravel.com/docs/5.1/events#queued-event-listeners) under "Manually accessing the queue".

Comment: how can i specify which job to delete? is that possible?

Comment: @ShazAmjad I appreciated the link, but the docs weren't enough to clarify for me how I could browse to a specific queued Mailable and then cancel/delete it. If you have ideas, my question is here: https://stackoverflow.com/q/48255735/470749 Thanks.